# How to protect client secret in REST API call in Oracle Autonomous Database

Tags: unity-game-engine, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-autonomous-db

I have a Unity3d based mobile game where I send REST API's to an Oracle Autonomous JSON database.

I realise that hard coding client secret in the client code is not good and I have been researching solutions to this. Unfortunately I know very little about this and reach out here to ask for advise and maybe a pointer to how I could solve this.

Comment: 1. You could keep the Client ID and secret in the OCI vault and retrieve them using OCI SDK vs coding them into your app

Comment: 2. You could use OCI API Gateway to restrict access to your APIs vs using the OAuth2 client.

Answer (score 0):

I will use Unity3d Cloud Code infrastructure to do the protection and execute the ORDS REST API calls from there.